# Blackmagic Pocket Firmware Modifikation

Tags: fpga

I'm trying to modify the FPGA firmware for the Blackmagic Pocket Camera. The camera's 60fps function is disabled. The sensor can handle 100fps. Blackmagic only provides Max. 30fps. So there is more to it than offered by Blackmagic.

The `*.bin` files can be found in the Blackmagic Camera Setup and only there. In all other versions the `*.bin` files are not to be found. It concerns the following files:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VBD7E-E-8eVjextm0Z2AjaX7u3NKRPEF/view

The FPGA chip is Spartan 6 from Xilinx

Is it possible to extract the firmware, then modify it and pack it back as firmware?

I hope for some tips.

Comment: Links like that often tend to go stale which puts everyone but the first few viewers at a disadvantage. It would be better if you could link to an official download location (provided that exists).

Comment: i don't have other way to provide the bin files. Can you recommend another alternative?

Comment: Edit: ...The *.bin files can be found in the Blackmagic Camera Setup >>Vers. 2.1<< and only there....

Comment: then don't worry. It is how it is. But in some cases the vendor who creates some hardware offers the firmware on a public website. This would have been ideal here.